# How to recursively check property types in an object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm writing a function that takes in an object (A), compares it with another object (B) and creates a new object (C). Both A and B objects are symmetrical (same amount of properties,  same keys) but the type of their values can differ. Eg: A.amount can be '11' while B.amount is a number. The end result should be an object C that has the values from A with the types from B.

In the function I came up with, I'm looping through all properties in object A, checking the type of the properties in object B with a switch/case statement, applying type conversion (like `.toString()`) and adding the corrected property to object C.

I would like the code to be recursive but as soon as there are nested objects involved I do not know how to reach the properties in B nor create the equivalent in C.

Example of an A object:

```
const data = {
    a: "15",
    b: "foo",
    c: false,
    d: {
          da: 99,
          db: [{
                 dba: "1.2",
                 dbb: true
              }]
       }
    }
```

Example of a B object:

```
const targetType = {
    a: 27,
    b: "foofoo",
    c: true,
    d: {
          da: "bar",
          db: [{
                 dba: 4,
                 dbb: false
              }]
       }
    }
```

Example of a C object -values from A, types from B:

```
const finalObject = {
    a: 15,
    b: "foo",
    c: false,
    d: {
          da: "99",
          db: [{
                 dba: 1.2,
                 dbb: true
              }]
       }
    }
```

My function:

```
//data = object A
//targetType = object B
export function typeConversion(data: any, targetType: any) {
  const resultObj = {};
  Object.keys(data).forEach((key) => {
    switch (typeof targetType[key]) {
      case 'string':
        resultObj[key] = data[key].toString();
        break;
      case 'boolean':
        resultObj[key] = data[key] ? 'Yes' : 'No';
        break;
      case 'number':
        resultObj[key] = Number(data[key]);
        break;
      //here is where it gets tricky:
      case 'object':
        if (Array.isArray(data[key])) {
          const dataArray: any = [];
          data[key].forEach((o) => {
            //all objs in the array have the same shape, hence comparing to [0]
            dataArray.push(typeConversion(o, targetType[key][0]));
          });
          resultObj[key] = dataArray;
        } else {
          const dataObj = {};
          Object.keys(data[key]).forEach((subkey) => {
            dataObj[subkey] = typeConversion(subkey, targetType[key][subkey]);
          });
          resultObj[key] = dataObj;
        }
        break;
    }
  });
  return resultObj;
}

console.log(typeConversion(data, targetType))
```

The moment there is a nested object and typeConversion is called recursively, it will fail to find the path to the property in object B. I could add an optional parameter to the function for the 'parent property', but that would only work for one level of depth.

If there is a way to make this recursive, it can't be by coding the path to `targetType[like][this]`.

[TypeScript Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noImplicitAny=false&target=7&module=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygmBeGBvAUDGCBcMARAIwCsRANDjAEaFEBmIIVNwhjCANhAKbVccQtlxCCMAJyTBYuPRgBtUWKG0JpAHQAmNqrUKoAJwCufGrgC+AXRqWs9rKEixkRgOZ8oAFQCeABz40TBoJbQB2WQUmFmZWWQ4YYzNZYRDVRAZ1Iz05BWULPIkAFlkM2gUuXnNVGzsHLCdwaBhGAEswHgB5WgArPmBYdBUJciiGONzEqv5UkULM4mlctUIC-Xh1QhIdMrzDUxqxOqsGrAB6c8RkYJA+gdgAQQvzt08fAKD0O-7BmAAhLB8AAe-hARlgjBMYEGbXASU+AGFwAA3PhGCBwsAACmuEgQYF8lCSCA8Xj8gUIBN8AEp0jBnC0jHwICZuFAer1ghhLABuGich6aADWfF8EFxSAQNM0zCMAFEEMAABbY7Gi2loAB89NwEAA7m0oCqYNioJ8QIwSWSPoFFBrrHSVKpgAh+DAAOTQIwddwe-CFVTM1nszn2sXWYJ48O+ayaKAgADKxl92Jp-I2uFozIQwoz+ld7o9tBY3D4BP9gbEwbZHL6Mcj6GjDpgAH5PQBNFkemCED0AORAHvzG2z5bzVcLQQ9YBMAFtaOjK5mYDXQ-WW+h+-PF0ZJcgG+mq1mcxONpdleigm0IDB9ZfmTAjTB3reU8Bhb4Axsp56fg9l0zNorWxR4jCMBBfE0G8wIg3x9wQQ8nWPMRGVgPFYMgqlCWCRRrBHTNmwjWVwUVFU1RAOlUB1Z0VxgS4eG4GAflvDokkvPBwMgmBlQQNF2KCCAEDnQTeMCYlLxhIJQDnfxSV9JIQCUAAGWw6LkKVMKg-wTAgVVzUCZEwDRDEsWxEBiTeclPgbRRVJpI91MsRy6LXOtegbKNNK43wCNqGA+GqXVMzQ+ApU5bk+RQ3BBUGEUxQlIjYxlOUyNVbFWVoDUqJo6KNOQMNMs3BFDNRdFMXADKTCysVLNJd4KT4WyiojFyV2cvz9DcsNirxTlOtOFcx1zAj7CsFzmSgEwjDAVcWVrfr6iaSAQDLTRuBAdwzSRMrTMqvE6ptRqHKAA)

All ideas welcome, perhaps I'm approaching the whole thing wrong.

Comment: can you write example of A, B end C ?

Comment: Thank you for checking, added examples of all objects

Comment: If this is really a TypeScript question (as opposed to a JavaScript one), then the example code is full of errors unrelated to your issue.  Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/mMMgkm) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: Added a playground example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some changes in your function to recursively create the final object. Although this is not `Typescript` specific problem, I wonder what is the use case for this :)

```js
const transform = (data, targetType) => {
  let finalObject = {};
  const keys = Object.keys(data);
  
  for (const key of keys) {
    // If key is Array [], recursively add each element in Array
    if (data[key] instanceof Array) {
      finalObject[key] = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < data[key].length; i++) {
        const res = transform(data[key][i], targetType[key][i]);
        finalObject[key].push(res);
      }
    }
    // If key is Object {}, recursively add Object keys
    else if (data[key] instanceof Object) {
      finalObject[key] = transform(data[key], targetType[key]);
    }
    // If key is Primitive, we can directly add key
    else {
      switch (typeof targetType[key]) {
        case 'string':
          finalObject[key] = data[key].toString();
          break;
        case 'boolean':
          finalObject[key] = data[key] ? 'Yes' : 'No';
          break;
        case 'number':
          finalObject[key] = Number(data[key]);
          break;
      }
    }
  }

  return finalObject;
};

const data = {
  a: "15",
  b: "foo",
  c: false,
  d: {
    da: 99,
    db: [{
      dba: "1.2",
      dbb: true
    }]
  }
}

const targetType = {
  a: 27,
  b: "foofoo",
  c: true,
  d: {
    da: "bar",
    db: [{
      dba: 4,
      dbb: false
    }]
  }
}

const finalObject = transform(data, targetType);
console.log('Final Object : ', finalObject);
```

Comment: Thank you! I would have not figured it out on my own. Regarding the use case, the final object is used to make an Excel report with [xlsx-template](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx-template). We are not completely in control of the input data, so we need to make sure the types are correct  ("11" to 11 for example). I'm switching the tag to JS to make it easier for other people with a similar issue to find.